# Inconsistency of EVR and sink writer flipping screen captured images vertically

Tags: ms-media-foundation

Using Media Foundation, I'm trying to capture the screen and record and render it with EVR at the same time. I've written a custom media source for this. It works almost perfectly.

The only problem is, by default without reversing the image, EVR renders the screen correctly, but the recorded video is vertically flipped. I'm literally passing the same `IMFSample` to the sinks. I reversed the image and it records just fine, but now EVR renders it vertically flipped. Why are EVR and sink writer inconsistent and is there a solution for this problem?

**Other possibly useful information:**

- Capture method: Buffer swapping with DirectX9
- Media type:

  ```
  check = MFExtern.MFCreateMediaType(out var mediaType);
  check = mediaType.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType.Video);
  check = mediaType.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFMediaType.RGB32);
  check = mediaType.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, (uint)MFVideoInterlaceMode.Progressive);
  check = mediaType.SetSize(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, (uint)mode.Width, (uint)mode.Height);
  check = mediaType.SetRatio(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, FrameRateNumerator, FrameRateDenominator);
  check = mediaType.SetRatio(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
  check = mediaType.SetBoolean(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, true);
  ```

Comment: We need more information about your topologie's program

Comment: @mofo77 I'm using the reader writer architecture. I just added EVR to your own sample and I came across the mentioned issue.

https://github.com/mofo7777/Stackoverflow/blob/master/ScreenCaptureEncode/Main.cpp

Comment: for now I would just say to use 2 IMF samples, one with reverse image and the other with no reverse image

Comment: @mofo77 Which samples are you exactly referring to?